# Wrong status is being echoing even after script ran successfully

Tags: scripts

```
#!/bin/sh
serverStatus=$(ps aux | grep server1 -c)
serverStop='/server/myscripts/stopServer.sh server1'
serverStart='/server/myscripts/startServer.sh server1'

$serverStop
sleep 60

echo "$serverStatus"  

if [ $serverStatus -ne 2 ]
then
        echo 'Alert: App Server1 is down'
        
                $serverStart

else
        echo 'Alert: App Server1 is up and running'
        
fi
```

Output:

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /server/myscripts/logs/server1/stopServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the server profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
ADMU4000I: Server server1 stop completed.

2

Alert: App Server1 is up and running
```

Output should be:

```
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /server/myscripts/logs/server1/stopServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the server profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
ADMU4000I: Server server1 stop completed.

1

Alert: App Server1 is down
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  If you would like us to audit some script, you will need to provide the script.  Please use [formatting with code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) so that we can accurately parse the information.  If you cannot figure out the markdown formatting, please copy-paste as-is and we can help you with editing via moderation. In addition to providing the script, you should provide more context and details.  Tell us what you are trying to do.  You should also include the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using

Comment: $serverStop
sleep 60

echo "$serverStatus"


-  Echo is not printing the correct status even if the server is stopped. I put sleep 60 also to increase the time to read the output but it did not work.
-I am seeing the server is stopped successfully but its still giving me status as server is still up.

Comment: So my if condition is not matching correctly.

Comment: Below is my script. i am automating the server restart through this script and calling server stop and start script inside it.

Comment: If you have lingering processes or your server spawns `grep -c` may give you 2. probably better to use `pgrep` with the pidfile option, or a systemd unit.

Comment: serverStop='/server/myscripts/stopServer.sh server1 
serverStart='/server/myscripts/startServer.sh server1'


$serverStop
sleep 60

echo "$serverStatus"

if [ $serverStatus -ne 2 ]
then
        echo 'Alert: App Server1 is down'
        
                $serverStart

else
        echo 'Alert: App Server1 is up and running'
        
fi

Comment: Output is:

ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /server/myscripts/logs/server1/stopServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the server profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
ADMU4000I: Server server1 stop completed.

2

Alert: App Server1 is up and running

Comment: Output should be:

output:  


ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           /server/myscripts/logs/server1/stopServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the server profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3201I: Server stop request issued. Waiting for stop status.
ADMU4000I: Server server1 stop completed.

1

Alert: App Server1 is down
and server start command call

Comment: As I said `grep server1 -c` counts anything containing *server1*, e.g., if you use a full path to your script or editor that contains *server1*. It will even count itself (that you can avoid with `grep -c '[s]erver1'`)